# «Не» с прилагательным после противительно-соединительного союза

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно, прилагательные

> 1. Я люблю как большие, так и не большие домики.

Здесь очевидное противопоставление: большие / не большие. Поэтому раздельное написание.

> 2. Я люблю большие домики и небольшие домики.

Здесь слитное написание, так как нет противопоставления большой/маленький, идет обычное перечисление: большой, маленький, но не средний.

> 3. Я люблю большие домики и не большие домики тоже.

Здесь раздельное написание, так как автору хочется передать противопоставление — как большие, так и не большие.

Корректны ли все 3 предложения?

И еще вдогонку:

> 4. Я люблю небольшие домики.

Здесь автору хочется передать утверждение, контекст ситуации — мы зашли в небольшой домик, и автор порадовался этому.

> 5. Я люблю не большие домики!

Здесь автору хочется передать противопоставление, контекст ситуации — мы зашли в большой домик, и автор раздосадован этим.

Comment: Простите, противительно-соединительный союз — это какой? Союз **как...так и** является сопоставительным. http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-031.htm

Comment: Я имел ввиду "и" самый универсальный союз. В (3) я употребляю "и" в значении "как...так и", получается в сопостовительной (а сопоставление это в частности противление одного другому) роли. В (2) я употребляю "и" в значении соединительного "и"

Comment: "Имел в виду" пишется раздельно.

Comment: Номер 5 звучит как-то неестественно. Обычно говорят: я не люблю большие домики (т. е. с отрицанием при глаголе, имхо)

Comment: @V.V.: да все нечётные с раздельным написанием диковато звучат.